# replace url paths using Regex

Tags: regex

How can I change the url of my images from this:

http://www.myOLDwebsite.com/**********.*** (i have gifs, jpgs, pngs)

to this:

http://www.myNEWwebiste.com/somedirectory/**********.***

Using REGexp text editor?

Really thanks for your time

[]'s

Mateus

Comment: txt, I have a huge list of images on the root of that url.. for this new website I have to move images to new folder, but the folders are the same.. like http://www.myOLDwebsite.com/test/ will be http://www.myNEWwebsite.com/test/, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Why use regex?

Using conventional means, replace:

```
src="http://www.myOLDwebsite.com/
```

with:

```
src="http://www.myNEWwebiste.com/somedirectory/
```

Granted, this assumes your image tags always follow the `'src="<url>"'` pattern, with double quotes and everything.

Using regex is of course also possible. Replace this:

```
(src\s*=\s*["'])http://www\.myOLDwebsite\.com/
```

with:

```
\1http://www.myNEWwebiste.com/somedirectory/
```

alternatively, if your text editor uses $ to mark back references:

```
$1http://www.myNEWwebiste.com/somedirectory/
```

*On second thought - why do your images have absolute URLs in the first place? Isn't that unnecessary?*

Comment: hey dude.. because I have folders following that path.. but I want to move only the images to a new location, and all my code is on a txt without html tags... ;)

Comment: Why "anyway"? I can't see where this answer would *not* do what you intend. Have you actually tried it?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the easiest way is probably to use sed in in-place mode:

```
sed -ir \
 's@http://www[.]myOLDwebsite[.]com/@http://www.myNEWwebsite.com/subdirectory/@g' \
 file1 file2 ...
```

If for some reason you need to actually interpret the HTML (rather than just do a simple string replacement), a quick script built around [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is going to be safer -- lots of people try to do HTML or XML parsing via regular expressions, but it's very hard if not impossible to cover all corner cases.

All that said, it'd be better if you were using relative links to not have your HTML depend on the server it's hosted on. See also the `<BASE HREF="...">` element you can put in your `<HEAD>` to specify a location all URLs are relative to; if you were using that, you'd only need to do a single replacement.

Comment: Don’t forget to escape the dots and close the delemiter after the substitution.

Comment: Just “\.” would also be fine.

Comment: thanks dude, but I have a long txt only... not tags, php, perl or python, just a giant txt with images at root...